# Youtube iframe api "getPlayerState" function undefined

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

There are multiple youtube videos playing in my site in a carousel. When a user click on a youtube video then I want to stop the auto scrolling of the carousel. Here is the code I am writing which is throwing me **"players[player_id].getPlayerState() is not a function"** error.

Also the youtube library is loading in my site from a thrid party javascript.

players = {};

```
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function(){
        $('.youtube-video iframe').each(function() {
            players[$(this).attr('id')] = new YT.Player($(this).attr('id'), {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange($(this).attr('id'))
                }
            });
        });

    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(player_id){
        return function(event) {
            if(players[player_id].getPlayerState() == 3 ||players[player_id].getPlayerState() == 1) {
                //stop the auto scrolling
            }

            if(players[player_id].getPlayerState() == 0 || players[player_id].getPlayerState() == 2) {
                //start auto scrolling.
            }
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if you can find the issue in my code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: add the html code ? where did you pass the id of the video ? when you play the video ?

Comment: I am passing the id of the video like "$(this).attr('id')".

Comment: How did you resolve this? I think I'm having the same issue, loading the YouTube Iframe API from a third-party script and getting "undefined" methods (actually all object members are mangled to one-letter names).

Answer (score 2):

You forgot some sample paramters like `videoId: $(this).attr('id')` and `events`
was not placed at the good place.

I post you the correct code :

**HTML**

```
  <div class="youtube-video" id="O1RHkPGb31Q"></div>
  <div class="youtube-video" id="VjRb3RjqncQ"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

players = {};
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function(){
        $('.youtube-video').each(
  function() {
    players[$(this).attr('id')] = new YT.Player($(this).attr('id'), 
    { 
      videoId: $(this).attr('id'), 
      events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange($(this).attr('id')) }
    });
  });
};

    function onPlayerStateChange(player_id){
        return function(event) {
            if(players[player_id].getPlayerState() == 3 || players[player_id].getPlayerState() == 1) {
                //stop the auto scrolling
                console.log("stop scolling video" + player_id);
            }

            if(players[player_id].getPlayerState() == 0 || players[player_id].getPlayerState() == 2) {
                //start auto scrolling.
              console.log("start scolling video" + player_id);
            }
        };
    }
```

Live demo : http://jsbin.com/nisetafoga/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks for your response. I havent passed video id because youtube videos are already loaded in my site. and I havent loaded youtube library because a third party javascript is loading it in my site. My problem is when I click on the youtube video then onPlayerStateChange function is triggering but insdie that it is throwing getPlayerState() function is undefined. Even When I try to output event.target.getVideoUrl() it is showing the function is undefined.

Comment: @savithraj post a live, hard to understand how you build your code